# I can not get MUPDF to compile in Android Studio. It works fine in Eclipse. NDK ERROR

Tags: android, android-ndk, mupdf

I have been at this for days!!! I have read and re-read all the posts I can find and I just can't figure it out.

I built the Mupdf for android and can import it to eclipse, build it and run it on my device alone no problem. However I am new to all of this and do not know how to integrate it into my existing project in Eclipse.

In Android Studio I can integrate it into my existing project but I can not get a succesfull build. I really want to use Android Studio but can not figure out why it will not build!

The ERROR I Get in Android Studio. This does not happen in Eclipse

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:mupdfdemo:assembleDebug]
:mupdfdemo:preBuild
:mupdfdemo:compileDebugNdk
make.exe: *** No rule to make target `C:\Apps\PDFLastTest\mupdfdemo\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/mupdf/C_\Apps\PDFLastTest\mupdfdemo\src\main\jni', needed by `C:\Apps\PDFLastTest\mupdfdemo\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/mupdf/C_\Apps\PDFLastTest\mupdfdemo\src\main\jni\mupdf.o'.  Stop.
Error:Execution failed for task ':mupdfdemo:compileDebugNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Android-ndk\android-ndk-r10c\ndk-build.cmd NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Apps\PDFLastTest\mupdfdemo\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=C:\Apps\PDFLastTest\mupdfdemo\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Apps\PDFLastTest\mupdfdemo\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\lib APP_ABI=all
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    make.exe: *** No rule to make target `C:\Apps\PDFLastTest\mupdfdemo\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/mupdf/C_\Apps\PDFLastTest\mupdfdemo\src\main\jni', needed by `C:\Apps\PDFLastTest\mupdfdemo\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/mupdf/C_\Apps\PDFLastTest\mupdfdemo\src\main\jni\mupdf.o'.  Stop.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 4.237 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: According to the Android docs, NDK is not yet available for Android Studio and is only supported on Eclipse

Comment: @Martin Hi Martin. I know this may be a dumb question but how do I integrate it into my existing eclipse package? I can not seem to find a clear tutorial on this and am brand new to it. Being that I have spent the last 3 weeks with Android Studio, the Eclipse way eludes me. I right click the target package and select build path but which option from there I have no clue.

Comment: @Martin or do I somehow build it outside of A.S.

Comment: You can build it outside of A.S. using ndk-build script, remove the  jni folder, rename libs into jniLibs and import it directly in A.S. For more information on how to deal with NDK and prebuilts inside Android Studio, you can refer to my article: http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/

Comment: @ph0b Thanks for the tip!! I conceded and downloaded Eclipse. It works great but I am going to try your suggestion as I like A.S. Better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed u/ph0b advice and built the library in eclipse and then included it in the app in Android Studio.

Comment: are you able to get the required result